# Macbook Pro will not connect to 3rd monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have:

- 2018 15" **MacBook** Pro.
- A [startech **dock** with 2 display ports](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F94KD1L)
- A simple usb-c to hdmi **adapter**

I am currently using the **dock** to run 2 monitors + the **macbook** screen. I was hoping I could hook up the **adapter** to the dock and a 3rd external monitor, doing this did nothing. I then tried connecting the 3rd monitor directly to the **macbook** with the **adapter**... still nothing.

If I unplug the **dock**, the monitor connected via the **adapter** works! ... but when I connect the **dock** back in... only one of the 2 monitors connected to it will turn on.

It's like after it identifies 2 monitors, it decides it doesn't want to connect another.

Is there any way for me to get 3 external monitors working?

Comment: Have you tried connecting the dock on the left side and the HDMI adapter on the right side? Each side of the MacBook Pro has 2 ports but only on one bus each.

Comment: I didn't, but I just did now and it is working... thanks.